# how to sort descending order in specific index of list without built-in in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

My problem is this.
`1. Input N`
`2. Input N numbers are entered in the list. For example, N is 5 means 3,2,1,2,4 or 1,2,9,7,5 or 4,2,1,3,8 whatever, N is 3 means 1,2,3 or 7,4,8 or 2,13,26 whatever.`

`3. Input A and B`

`4. Sort descending order list only in index A to B. For example, N = 7 , input numbers are 3 2 0 6 7 9 1, A=2, B=5, the output is [3, 2, 9, 7, 6, 0, 1]`

my output is like this
[3, 2, 6, 0, 7, 9, 1]
[3, 2, 7, 0, 6, 9, 1]
[3, 2, 9, 0, 6, 7, 1]
[3, 2, 9, 6, 0, 7, 1]
[3, 2, 9, 7, 0, 6, 1]
[3, 2, 9, 0, 7, 6, 1]
[3, 2, 9, 0, 6, 7, 1]

The problem is last 2 output is so weird, I don't know what am i doing wrong.

```py
n = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(n):
    list.append(int(input()))

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
b+=1
tmp=0

for i in range(a,b):
    for j in range(a+1,b):
        if list[i]<list[j]:
            tmp=list[i]
            list[i]=list[j]
            list[j]=tmp
            print(list)
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use a selection sort. maybe this can help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-selection-sort/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
n = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(n):
    list.append(int(input()))

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
b+=1
tmp=0

for i in range(a,b):
    for j in range(i+1,b):
        if list[i]<list[j]:
            tmp=list[i]
            list[i]=list[j]
            list[j]=tmp
            print(list)
```

Comment: Thanks. a+1 was wrong. really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can swap two values in a `list` like this:

```py
list_[i], list_[j] = list_[j], list_[i]
```

---

One suggestion to you: `Don't use built-in data-type names as variable names.`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to simplify this for yourself, and maybe try without loops.

Your list generation, only with added input-directions and changing the list-name to "main":

```
n = int(input("n:"))
main = []
for i in range(n):
    main.append(int(input(f'{i+1} of {n}:')))
a = int(input("a:"))
b = int(input("b:"))
```

Now split your list into the respective parts, and use the built in .sort() function.

```
# Slice into three parts
start = main[:a]
mid = main[a:b+1]
end = main[b+1:]
# Sort the middle, descending
mid.sort(reverse = True)
# Re-combine the lists
main = start + mid + end
print(main)
```